# Fetch the latest pkg from github

Tags: github, travis-ci, swiftlint

I use this script to install swiftlint on travis:

```
set -e

SWIFTLINT_PKG_PATH="/tmp/SwiftLint.pkg"
SWIFTLINT_PKG_URL="https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/releases/download/0.25.1/SwiftLint.pkg"
wget --output-document=$SWIFTLINT_PKG_PATH $SWIFTLINT_PKG_URL

if [ -f $SWIFTLINT_PKG_PATH ]; then
  echo "SwiftLint package exists! Installing it..."
  sudo installer -pkg $SWIFTLINT_PKG_PATH -target /
else
  echo "SwiftLint package doesn't exist. Compiling from source..." &&
  git clone https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint.git /tmp/SwiftLint &&
  cd /tmp/SwiftLint &&
  git submodule update --init --recursive &&
  sudo make install
fi
```

It's not the best way to always update it if needed in this script - is it possible to point to always the latest released pkg?

Answer (score 0):

You can get info about last release from API: https://api.github.com/repos/realm/SwiftLint/releases/latest

To get tag name:

```
curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/realm/SwiftLint/releases/latest" | 
    grep -Po '"tag_name": "\K.*?(?=")'
```

To get download URL for `pkg` file:

```
curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/realm/SwiftLint/releases/latest" |
    grep -Po '"browser_download_url": "\K.*?.pkg(?=")'
```

[Source of one-liners](https://gist.github.com/lukechilds/a83e1d7127b78fef38c2914c4ececc3c#gistcomment-2552690).